# Change color of circular edit button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

How can I change the image for the delete button in a table view cell?

I mean the red circle button on the left side:

[image]

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290766/change-the-color-of-default-red-color-delete-button-in-uitableviewcell-when-swip

Answer (score 2):

Override the following in your `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if(state == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
    {
        for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
                UIImageView *customButton = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:v.bounds];
                [customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"]];
                [v addSubview:customButton];
                [v bringSubviewToFront:customButton];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can play with the subviews and the states to achieve your preferred result.

Comment: this method not called :(

Comment: @AndreyEvstratenko, I have tried this code before submitting. Please make sure you have a `UITableViewCell` subclass and this method in it and your table returns cells of that type in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: oooooh... sorry! i found a bug!)

Comment: This method gets called when the table view changes its state, e.g. from or to **editing** state. Make sure you call something like `[tableView setEditing:YES]`